# Unable to git checkout my branch having pdf files (with date time stamp)

Tags: git

I'm unable to git checkout a branch having multiple pdf files, like below

As you can see below from my 'Reports' folder, when I have only 'Summary.pdf' file, I can checkout my branch without any errors, however when I have *.pdf files with date time stamp I'm unable to checkout, Please help
[image]

Error Message:
An internal error occurred during: "Checking out ProjectRepo - refs/remotes/origin/master".
Invalid path: ProjectRepo/Reports/Summary_2020-03-31:15:26:43.pdf

Comment: Hmm colons in file name, could be a bad idea perhaps. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Git+colons+in+file+name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told us what operating system you're using, but I suspect it's Windows.  Windows paths cannot contain colons except for in the drive component.  This isn't Git's fault, but instead a deficiency in Windows.

If you need to check them out on your system, you can use Windows Subsystem for Linux and clone the repository there, then access it either under the Linux-based environment or via a `\\$wsl\` path.  Otherwise, you'll need to use a different operating system to check it out, or ask the person who created the repository to rename the files such that they don't have the colon in the name.

If you know what you're doing, you can also script the file replacement with `git update-index --index-info` to do the rename yourself and then commit.

Comment: Sure, Thanks @matt, bk2204. Yes, I'm using windows. I'll rename files as it is simple and quicker solution for the time being!